# Is there usage of Haskell Repa slice function analogous to Vector and other languages?

Tags: arrays, haskell, vector, repa

I am trying to get a usable version of multidimensional arrays in Haskell, comparable to that of `numpy` arrays in Python and other languages.
I found other questions about how to write custom functions for arrays of specific dimensions, but my objective it more to the point, get a similar behavior of `Data.Vector`'s `slice` function, which is intuitive and does the job of bracket-indexed arrays of other languages.

`Vector`'s `slice` function has type
`V.slice :: Int -> Int -> V.Vector a -> V.Vector a`

so slicing a vector `v` is as simple as

```
import Data.Vector as V
let v = V.fromList [1..10]
    i = 1
    j = 5
V.slice i j v
```

`Repa`'s `slice` on the other hand has type

`R.slice :: (R.Slice sl, R.Shape (R.FullShape sl), R.Source r e) => R.Array r (R.FullShape sl) e -> sl -> R.Array R.D (R.SliceShape sl) e`

so it takes a Repa array and a shape and return a delayed array.
I understand that Repa does not take Integers as indices, but I am looking for a general use of the `slice` function for arbitrary dimension, whether using `Repa`'s `(Z :. i)` or `ixn` dimension specification.

I'm not looking for a dimension-dependent function using `traverse`, and would prefer not to go into any template haskell to generalize that, although if it's not possible to use the `slice` function generally it is what it is.

The question is, then: is it possible to use `Repa`'s `slice` function to get arbitrary slices of multidimensional arrays, like in `numpy`'s v[x1:x2,y1:y2] or C++ `Eigen`'s `matrix.block<p,q>(i,j)`?

Comment: `numpy's v[x1:x2,y1:y2]` means to get the elements of index (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2) and return the result as 2 x 2 metrix?

Comment: It means getting all elements in the first dimension (which I'm calling x) between indices `x1` and `x2`, and the second dimension (y) between `y1` and `y2`.
In Python getting those elements you mention would be then x1,x2 = y1,y2 = 1,3, or v[1:3,1:3], which would be a 2x2 matrix indeed since `numpy` arrays don't include the last index.
In Haskell `V.slice 1 2 v` would do the analogous operation for a single dimension, but doing that for 2 or more is not straightforwardly described in `Repa`'s tutorial or documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the closest equivalent is [extract](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.1.4/docs/Data-Array-Repa-Operators-IndexSpace.html#v:extract), which takes a starting index (like `ix2 x1 y1`) and a size (like `ix2 (x2-x1) (y2-y1)`).

The result of `extract` always has the same number of dimensions as the input, but can have different size in each dimension.  The result of `slice` can have a different number of dimensions, but in any given dimension it takes either all elements or exactly one.  (Based on the instances for `Shape` and `Slice`.)

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work alright.. Still pretty cumbersome compared to other languages and even to Vector.slice. I can deal with the array keeping the same number of dimensions and size 1 along the dimension of the slice, it's not ideal but workable in the absence of analog usage of Repa.slice.